# SSH'ing into WIN 10

Tags: ssh, bash, windows-10, ssh-keys

People of the Server-verse, a humble hello from fellow apprentice.

Above line goes out to show i am a newbie and thus need help with trivial probs, so appreciate all help in advance.

I am facing 2 issues that need help with while ssh'ing into win 10 home edition pc from either a linux / macos.

1. It still asks for password even though i copied my (linux/macos) id_rsa.pub key into authorized_keys file (of win10). Also to point out I copied the keys manually since `ssh-copy-id` was not working due to issue #2
2. How do i change default shell when i log into win10, currently i am greeted with command prompt, as shown below, I have bash (WSL) and would like to have it default prompt when I ssh into it.

`Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1466]`

`(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`

`panda@DESKTOP-TEST C:\Users\panda>`

Answer (score 1):

I presume you installed the Microsoft β-release of native openssh server?

Microsoft documentation explains how to deploy ssh keys using Powershell on serverside.

Nevertheless, in your still want bash:

2/ The shell provided by Microsoft can be configured adding a property in the registry:

> New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
> Blockquote

You can also use a “bash” script to modify your %PATH% and add any flavor of third party bash you may have installed on the server (cygwin, msys, git-bash…).

1/ try again ssh-copy-id :) BUT keep in mind that only ed25519 keys may work.
`you@unix$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519` may save your day. Maybe not: I am unsure of the openssh implementation of Microsoft and the ACL management will probably prevent you from login in after the ssh key deployment if the ACLs (and their administrator_authorized_keys mechanism) is not correctly fixed.

BTW: the microsoft documentation are pretty clear.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration and
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement

Comment: i got the bash to open up on SSH part working, however looking at the resources from MS web links (thank you for those) it is not only ed25519 that works, i will update once i get that tried out